# mvc3 model string array property getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, arrays

In my application I have a

Public Class HomeIndexClientModel

I declare these properties:

```
Public strButtonBarProblemGuid() As String
Public strButtonBarProblemTitle() As String
Public strButtonBarButtonToRender() As String
```

In my Sub New i have a loop in my Linq where the following is happening:

```
            ReDim Preserve Me.strButtonBarButtonToRender(intButtonCount)  'set the size of the button bar array
            ReDim Preserve Me.strButtonBarProblemTitle(intButtonCount) 'set the size of the button bar array
            ReDim Preserve Me.strButtonBarButtonToRender(intButtonCount) 'set the size of the button bar array
```

If i follow that with

Me.strButtonBarProblemGuid(intButtonCount - 1) = "AA" 'p.SystemUserFileId.ToString

I get the error.

I have tried messing with 0 index or 1  in teh array offset but both fail the same way

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without your LINQ statements, it's tough to see what's going on to set those variables.  Please post the entire statement.

The LINQ statement is likely placing NULLs into those variables that you're performing a ReDim on.